# How to cast JSON array to array with SwiftyJSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

I have a JSON array `var array: [JSON] = []` that I would like to cast as a 'regular' array so that I can perform some filtering and other data manipulation. What would be the suggested approach to do so?

I've tried `let filteredArray = array.arrayValue.filter {$0["submission_id"] as! Int == 27}` but I was thrown this error

> Value of type '[JSON]' has no member 'arrayValue'

Comment: What library are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: I'm using swiftyjson and alamofire

Comment: If the type is `[JSON]` then that is already a "regular array". `array.filter` should work.

Comment: I've tried that too but I would get a _Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type 'Int' always fails_

Comment: Then your question is "How do I get an Int out of a Swiftyjson JSON object"?

Comment: `$0["submission_id"].double` should give you a double, that's close ...

Comment: @Thilo I'm sorry but I don't quite follow.. Why do I put `.double`? The values are all `int`. If it helps, I'm actually using the swift Dollar library for data manipulation of arrays

Comment: Maybe there is `.integer` as well. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A SwiftyJSON object has an index and content.

To filter a SwiftyJSON object, you can use `filter` but you have to filter on the second part of the tuple, the content.

Also, you should use the `.int` property generated by SwiftyJSON if you want to get the Int value.

Example:

```
let filtered = json.filter { $0.1["submission_id"].int == 27 }
```

But you can also extract the contents of the SwiftyJSON object to get a Swift array, with `.arrayObject`.

Then you would filter like this:

```
if let array = json.arrayObject {
    let filtered = array.filter { $0["submission_id"] as? Int == 27 }
}
```